# Compress Weblogic logs

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have a requirement to compress Weblogic logs.

I checked Weblogic console settings for logging and I see that I can rotate the logs but did not see any property that I can set for compression(to zip file) of logs.

Current settings are as shown in image.

[image]

Is there any to compress these logs automatically?

Answer (score 1):

WebLogic Server does not provide this feature. You will have to handle compression using your own shell scripts for instance